# Why does second initialiser in base class break compilation?

Tags: swift

Given a base class, a derived class and an extension with a convenience initializer, the compiler throws an error if a second initializer is added to the base class like in the following [sscce](http://www.sscce.org)

```
#!/usr/bin/env swift 
class A {
    required init(a : Int){}
    init(b: Int){} // when removing this initializer everything works fine
}

class B: A {
    required init(a : Int){ super.init(a: a) }
}

extension A {
    convenience init(c : Int) { self.init(a: c) }
}

let b: B = B(c: 1)
```

With the two initializers in the base class the following error is thrown:

```
... error: incorrect argument label in call (have 'c:', expected 'a:')
let b: B = B(c: 1)
            ^~
             a
```

Apart from an error message which is not very helpful in this case, I am not quite sure if this is expected behaviour or a bug in swift.

Swift version info:

```
Apple Swift version 5.0.1 (swiftlang-1001.0.82.4 clang-1001.0.46.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
```

Comment: The problem is fixed if you override `init(b:)` in `class B`.

Comment: @maddy that's a good point, except that it doesn't make sense to have the second initializer on the derived class in the real world code that lead to this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Automatic Initializer Inheritance](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID222):

> Assuming that you provide default values for any new properties you introduce in a subclass, the following two rules apply:
>
> Rule 1
> If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.
>
> Rule 2
> If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass convenience initializers.

Without `init(b:)` in `class A`, `class B` automatically inherits `init(c:)` from the extension and everything works.

But when you add `init(b:)` to `class A`, then `class B` no longer follows either rule and therefore `class B` no longer automatically inherits the `init(c:)` from the extension. This results in the error since `class B` now only has the one `init(a:)` initializer and no others.

You can fix the problem by overriding `init(b:)` in `class B`. With that in place, `class B` again automatically gets the `init(c:)` from the extension.